# Differentiation of a double integral

Tags: integration, derivatives

I have to compute the following:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{db}\int_x^b \left (\int_s^b f(y)dy \right)g(s)ds
\end{equation}

Comment: Do you specific functions $f(y)$ and $g(s)$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [Leibniz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule),

$$
\begin{align}
  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} b}
  \int_x^b \left( \int_s^b f(y) \,\mathrm{d}y \right) g(s) \,\mathrm{d}s
&= \int_x^b
   \frac{\partial}{\partial b}
   \left( \int_s^b f(y) \,\mathrm{d}y \right)
   g(s) \,\mathrm{d}s
 + \left( \int_s^b f(y) \,\mathrm{d}y \right) g(s)
   \frac{\mathrm{d} s}{\mathrm{d} b} \Big|_{s=x}^b \\
&= \int_x^b f(b) g(s) \,\mathrm{d}s
 + \left( \int_b^b f(y) \,\mathrm{d}y \right) g(b)
 - \left( \int_x^b f(y) \,\mathrm{d}y \right) g(x)
   \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} b} \\
&= \int_x^b f(b) g(s) \,\mathrm{d}s
 - g(x) \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} b} \cdot \int_x^b f(y) \,\mathrm{d}y.
\end{align}
$$

In particular if $x$ does not depend on $b$, this reduces to
$$ \int_x^b f(b) g(s) \,\mathrm{d}s. $$

Answer (score 0):

Take the thing within the bracket as some $h(s)$ So you have to $$\frac{d}{db} \int_x^b h(s)g(s)ds$$ which is (as I think) $$h(b)g(b)$$

Now $h(b)$ is $0$ so the answer should be $0$ I guess..